# Admob crash my app

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to add ads to my android app. Its going well, and I see the layout showing up. The problem is, when I try to request the app through the onCreate function in my main java file it crashes.

Here is the code I am adding when it crashes:

Xml file

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    ads:adSize="BANNER" 
    ads:adUnitId="ID"> 
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Java file:

```
//request and load the ad. 
AdView mAdView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView); 
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Manifest file:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
    </activity>
```

Please help me

Comment: Without your full `onCreate` and a logcat it will be hard to pinpoint your issue. A guess would be you are missing `setContentView()` within your `onCreate`.

Comment: There is no way for us to help you with a crash if you don't even include the crash output.